# Why is the title (a string) of my v-select being broken into newlines at the spaces?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-select

The v-select v-model value is broken into new lines at spaces when user clicks to open dropdown.

I have tried styling (white-space) to solve the issue.  I've also tried changing the string to an array and looping through the array but that seems like overkill.  I am using JS, https://vue-select.org/ and Vue.  I am not using Vuetify's v-select.

My data:

```
data: () => ({
    selectedTitle: "Job Title"
}),
```

The v-select:

```
<v-select
    class="job-title-select"
    :options="titles"
    v-model="selectedTitle"
    @change="(entry) => this.updateCriteria(entry, 'Job Title')"
    taggable/>
```

Note: updateCriteria() is sending data to the store.  It doesn't affect the v-select display or local value changes. v-model does.

Expected: I should see the value as "Job Title", "Director of Stuff", on one line when the user clicks on the v-select.

Outcome: When user expands/clicks on dropdown, this is what appears as the title for the dropdown element (these are not dropdown items):

```
Job
Title

Director
Of
Stuff
```

Comment: The output above is displaying incorrectly.  Ex: In "Job Title", it would not have an empty line between "Job" and "Title". I tried to edit to show the outcome properly but no luck.

Comment: I attempted to edit to show output correctly ... let me know if that's correct.

Comment: What library are you using for v-select?

Comment: @DanielOrmeño Vue's v-select (vue-select).  I had to do this in my main.js: import vSelect from 'vue-select'; as Vuetify's v-select would not work.

Comment: @TonyAbrams They aren't dropdown items but the spacing of "Job Title" and "Director of Stuff" displays as the outcome now so thanks!

Comment: can you update the question and include what `updateCriteria` does

Comment: what is in the css class job-title-select?

Comment: @TonyAbrams .job-title-select {
  background-color: $color--light;
  font-size: 12px;
  z-index: 16;
  margin: 16px 0 30px 16px;
  border: none;
  width: 305px;
  height: 30px !important;
}

Comment: I was messing around in CodePen, but can't reproduce -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMvrEq?editors=1111

Comment: You are using Vuetify's v-select.  I am using this: https://vue-select.org/  I mentioned it in a comment above but not in the initial post, sry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that vue-select has conflicts with Bulma.  I removed Bulma as a dependency and everything was fine.

https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+bulma